# NumPy zeros in Numba function is not working when multi-dimensional shape is a list

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numba

I tried giving numba a go, as I was told it works very well for numerical/scientific computing applications. However, it seems that I've already run into a problem in the following scenario:

I have a function that computes a 12x12 Jacobian matrix, represented by a numpy array, and then returns this Jacobian. However, when I attempt to decorate said function with `@numba.njit`, I get the following error:

> This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
>   the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

As a basic example of my usage, the following code tries to declare a 12x12 numpy zero matrix, but it fails:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit
def numpy_matrix_test():
    A = np.zeros([12,12])
    return A

A_out = numpy_matrix_test()
print(A_out)
```

Since I assumed declaring numpy arrays in such a way was common enough that numba would be able to handle them, I'm quite surprised.

Comment: np.zeros([12,12]) is the wrong syntax, but numpy accepts it anyway. The right way would be np.zeros((12,12)). (np.zeros expects a tuple and not a list)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The assumption that the functions called in a numba jitted function are the same functions when not used in a numba function is actually **wrong** (but understandable). In reality numba (behind the scenes) delegates to its own functions instead of using the "real" NumPy functions.

So it's not really `np.zeros` that is called in the jitted function, it's [their own function](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/0.44.1/numba/targets/arrayobj.py#L3369-L3375). So some differences between Numba and NumPy are unavoidable.

For example you cannot use a list for the shape, it has to be a **tuple** (lists and arrays produce the exception you've encountered). So the correct syntax would be:

```
@numba.njit
def numpy_matrix_test():
    A = np.zeros((12, 12))
    return A
```

Something similar applies to the dtype argument. It has to be a **real** NumPy/numba type, a Python type cannot be used:

```
@numba.njit
def numpy_matrix_test():
    A = np.zeros((12, 12), dtype=int)  # to make it work use numba.int64 instead of int here
    return A
```

Even if "plain" NumPy allows it:

```
np.zeros((12, 12), dtype=int)
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention, this is the case for using complex types as well. For example, `dtype=complex` will throw the same error. Using `dtype=numba.complex64` or `dtype=numba.complex128` resolves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Do you perhaps mean numpy.zeros((12,12)), because you want a shape of 12 rows and 12 columns?
[Numpy Zeros reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)